# ¿Es necesario instalar Java JRE para programar en Java?

Tags: java

Alguien me prodria decir sí es necesario instalar java JRE (Java Runtime Environment para programar en java, porque hace poco salió Java SE 14 pero no se sí es necesario instalar JRE porque se quedó en la versión 8. ¿Es necesario instalar Java SE para trabajar con el IDE eclipse? O java SE es lo mismo que JDK.

Answer (score 1):

El **JRE**, como su nombre indica, es solamente el entorno de ejecución para aplicaciones Java por lo que solo contiene los comandos necesarios para este fin. Desde Java 9 ya casi ningún vendor distribuye un JRE, excepto [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) (por lo menos que yo conozca). Esto es así porque ahora la idea es que los desarrolladores creen su propia runtime image (un JRE personalizado) utilizando la herramineta `jlink` y conteniendo solo los módulos que necesite su aplicación.

No obstante de lo anterior, el **JDK** siempre ha contenido también las herramientas requeridas para ejecutar las aplicaciones, por lo que para el desarrollo no necesitamos un JRE independiente.

**Java SE** no tiene nada que ver con JDK o JRE. Este término se refiere al núcleo principal del lenguaje el cual incluye la biblioteca estándar (las funcionalidades principales del lenguaje). Por lo tanto con el JDK y con el JRE tenemos acceso al Java SE.

Por último, para desarrollar aplicaciones Java **siempre** es necesario utilizar el JDK.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Es necesario instalar Java JRE para programar en Java?

Sí, un Runtime es necesario, si no lo tienes, no se ejecuta el programa que hace uso de él, los SDKs incluyen los runtimes.

> ¿Es necesario instalar Java SE para trabajar con el IDE eclipse?

Sí, es la plataforma de Java. Inclusive sin ese IDE puedes programar, usarías pura línea de comandos si así lo quieres intentar.

> ¿O java SE es lo mismo que JDK?

Desde la wikipedia:

> Java Platform, Standard Edition o Java SE (conocido anteriormente hasta la versión 5.0 como Plataforma Java 2, Standard Edition o J2SE), es una colección de APIs del lenguaje de programación Java útiles para muchos programas de la Plataforma Java. La Plataforma Java 2, Enterprise Edition incluye todas las clases en el Java SE, además de algunas de las cuales son útiles para programas que se ejecutan en servidores sobre workstations.

Y JDK

> Java Development Kit (JDK) es un software que provee herramientas de desarrollo para la creación de programas en Java. Puede instalarse en una computadora local o en una unidad de red.

Answer (score -1):

Para desarrollar es necesario el JDK, este tiene implicito el JRE, dado que para el test de las aplicaciones es importante tener este Runtime enviroment para poder correr las aplicaciones.